# OpenGl ES : Ray Picking for multiple objects drawn using push/pop matrix

Tags: opengl-es

i got a question regarding multiple objects drawn using push/ pop stack.something similar to this.

---

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    glTranslatef(x,y,z);  
    glRotate(r,1,0,0);              
    glTranslate(-x,-y,-z); 

    for (i=0 to 20) objects         
      glpushMatrix();    
           draw_object()         
      glpopMatrix();    
     end
```

---

each object is a unit circle with its own transformation.  In such a case how does ray picking work. How should i keep track of center point of the object to calculate ray intersection. i really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current matrix for the each object:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
glLoadIdentity();  
glTranslatef(x,y,z);  
glRotate(r,1,0,0);              
glTranslate(-x,-y,-z);     

for (i=0 to 20) objects         
  glpushMatrix();    
      ... some matrix transformations specific for the object
      ... and get the final matrix and store it to object member
      glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (GLfloat*)&object->modelMatrix);
      draw_object()         
  glpopMatrix();
```

When doing ray intersection just multiply the object matrix with local center point coordinate to get it in absolute space where ray is defined.